# How to name LADSPA filter in pavucontrol?

Tags: pulseaudio

I load several LADSPA filters using commands of the sort:

```
pacmd load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=equalizer sink_properties=device.description=equalizer master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo plugin=filters label=Parametric1 control=1,0,1,200,0.5,-6,1,400,0.5,-1,1,1000,0.5,0,1,2000,0.5,0
```

Despite using `sink_properties=device.description=equalizer` and `sink_name=equalizer`, the media stream name in pavucontrol 'Playback' tab still shows this stram as `LADSPA Stream on`. With several such filters loaded it becomes a process of trial and error when trying to connect sinks and sources.
It seems the sink name can be set from its index via:

```
pacmd update-sink-input-proplist $stream_index media.name="equalizer"
```

Where the `stream_index` can be found from `pacmd list-sink-inputs`.... if you can find the corresponding stream. But with several LADSPA filters loaded there appears to be no unique identifier in the output of `pacmd list-sink-inputs`, so I'm back at trial and error.

Is there some way to specify the stream name, or uniquely identify this index?